# python in the command line is not working

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, command-line, pycharm, pythonpath

I use python in PyCharm and VSCode and everything works there. Now I want to install the package `pymongo` via the command line. When I try this I get:

```
No Python at D:\Python\python.exe
```

I know the path is wrong because this is a previous version's path. But I don't know how to change this. I've already tried adding the new path to the environment variables, but that doesn't solve the problem either.

I hope you can help me

Comment: did You restart the cmd? after changing environmental variables?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: I use Microsoft Windows 10 Home

Comment: yes, i restarted the cmd

Comment: just switch to linux, vim, and a cmd line that deserves the word ;)

Comment: How have you installed Python? What command are you running to install pymongo?

Comment: @supermarii -Could you use python from a system terminal outside of VS Code? It is recommended that you check the environment variables of python or you could reinstall python and check "Add to the Path" and then reopen VS Code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You have to find out where your Python is installed.